# How To Generate a Direction Field and Solve a System of Differential Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to draw a direction field and solve this system of differential equations using Mathematica, but I've been researching, and I can't find a way to do this:

$$\mathbf{x'} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 4 & -2 \end{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}$$

Note: I'm still a newbie to Mathematica, so please be patient with me. Thanks!

Comment: You could start by presenting your equations explicitly, rather than in matrix form (I am not sure how to interpret them). Then study the documentation of `DSolve` and give it a try, then report back with your code attempts.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: @MarcoB Answer updated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to draw a direction field and solve this system of differential
>   equations

Like this

```
f1 = x1 + x2
f2 = 4* x1 - 2 x2;
StreamPlot[{f1, f2}, {x1, -3, 3}, {x2, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The x axis is `x1` and the y axis is `x2`. These are the two state variables. From the phase plot, it looks like origin is saddle point. To verify, look at eigenvalues

```
A = {{1, 1}, {4, -2}};
Eigenvalues[A]

(* {-3, 2} *)
```

Yes, saddle point. One eigenvalue is stable and the other is not stable.

Comment: Can you explain why do we use StreamPlot instead of dfield in this case? When should we use one over the other? And thanks for your answer, that's what I'm looking for -- I really appreciate it!

Comment: @TuanDucVu `dfield` is matlab's and `StreamPlot` is what I use in Mathematica. They are used to make `phase plot`, i.e plotting one state variable against another.  So when using Mathematica you can use `StreamPlot` to make phase plots. I use it for all my school hw's myself. Easy to use.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Update: I finally got a hang of how to solve the system after reading the documentation of `DSolve`. Here is a snippet of code:

```
A = {{1,1},{4,-2}};
X[t_]={x[t],y[t]};
DSolve[X'[t] == A.X[t],X[t],t]
```

Comment: Glad to see this! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Since you've now figured out how to use `DSolve[]`, allow me to present another tool you can use.

As you might be aware, the one-dimensional first order ODE

$$y^\prime(t)=a y(t)$$

has a solution that can be expressed as $y(t)=C\exp(a t)$, where $C$ is determined through an appropriate initial condition.

In complete analogy, a first order ODE with *matrix* coefficient $\mathbf A$:

$$\mathbf y^\prime(t)=\mathbf A\mathbf y(t)$$

can be expressed in terms of the *[matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)*. *Mathematica* has this built-in as `MatrixExp[]`, so that the supposed result of

```
DSolve[{X'[t] == {{1, 1}, {4, -2}}.X[t], X[0] == {C[1], C[2]}}, X[t], t]
```

can in fact be immediately written down as

```
y[t_] = MatrixExp[{{1, 1}, {4, -2}} t, {C[1], C[2]}]
```

and you can easily check that this satisfies the ODE:

```
D[%, t] - {{1, 1}, {4, -2}}.% // Simplify
   {0, 0}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It's really clever!